# MySQL, how to use subtraction with time stamp?

Tags: php, mysql

i have this table called `test` with one field called  `times`.

and i insert a time into is in a UNIX time stamp format: `1318055933`

then i want do an update where the (current time - times) > 600

```
UPDATE test SET times= 0 WHERE (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - times> 600);
```

this query doesn't seem to work,

any ideas what i am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: What fieldtype is 'times' ? If its a datetime type, you'll have to calculate different, it'd be easier actually and would make more sense if you use datetime functions more often.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try casting the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function to a signed integer.

```
UPDATE test SET times= 0 WHERE (CAST(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() AS SIGNED) - times> 600);
```

I found this in the [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp). Depending on the data type of the `times` column, you might have to cast that as well.

> If you want to subtract `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` columns, you might want to cast the result to signed integers. See Section 11.10, “Cast Functions and Operators”.